# Enable or disable context menu from vb.net code

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I have following context menu which should only be enabled if my "Globals.admin = true". 
I have other context menus bound specificaly for some button, label, control, etc. My idea is to enable/disable this context menu bellow based on state of "Globals.admin" in my vb.net code

```
<ContextMenu x:Key="cm">
        <MenuItem Header="Block" Click="MenuItem_Click" />
        <MenuItem Header="Unblock" Click="MenuItem2_Click"/>
        <MenuItem Header="-"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Hide="MenuItem3_Click"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Show="MenuItem4_Click"/>
    </ContextMenu>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind the `IsEnabled` property to your static source property:

```
<ContextMenu x:Key="cm" IsEnabled="{Binding Source={x:Static local:Globals.admin}}">
    <MenuItem Header="Block" Click="MenuItem_Click" />
    <MenuItem Header="Unblock" Click="MenuItem2_Click"/>
    <MenuItem Header="-"/>
    <MenuItem Header="Hide" />
    <MenuItem Header="Show" />
</ContextMenu>
```